# Count consecutive values above threshold for all columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following df:

```
       A      B      C
0     47     50     22
1     47     53     28
2     47     65     33
3     47     62     33
4     47     62     33
5     47     62     33
6     47     62     33
7     47     62     33
```

I'd like to create an array with the amount of times that any value repeats itself more than 5 times and sum it. In the above example the output that I'd like it would be:

```
output = [8 5 6]
```

Is there a way to do it using `pandas` methods? I almost got the correct output but using for loops and it takes too long since I have +1000 columns and almost 7000 rows.

Comment: Hello! What if you have two different integers with the same frequency (greater than 5)?

Comment: You can do it using Counter() from collections library

Comment: Are you counting each column separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
s=df.melt()
s.value.value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>=5]
47    8
33    6
62    5
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Update

```
s=df.melt()
s.groupby(list(s)).size().loc[lambda x : x>=5]
variable  value
A         47       8
B         62       5
C         33       6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey @YOBEN_S, it's almost that, I'd like to assignt the count to each column so at the `output` array I'd have only a count according to the ['A' 'B' 'C'] labels. Which value is repeating itself is not important to me, only the count for each column

Comment: Oh that's perfect! This works pefectly now, thank you so much!!

Comment: is it possible that this solution has a limitation regarding the threshold? I increased to 72 consecutive values and I think it's returning me the amount o 47, for example, values that exists in the dataframe, not specifically consecutive values.

Comment: @PedrodeSá could you please share more info about that ?

Comment: Sure, I actually have this huge dataframe (46355 rows × 1349 columns) and I think it was working when I was testing for a significantly small df and with thresholds smaller as well, like 5. When I tried this code with my actual df, it returned me values that I don't think are real. Instead of looking for 72 consecutive values and counting, I think it's returning me only the amount of occurrences of that value on the code.

Comment: @PedrodeSá I got you , `s=df.ne(df.shift()).cumsum();
s.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts()`

Comment: sorry I didn't understand it. Why did you remove the `loc` method? I'd still like to filter the values that repeats itself more than a certain amount of values

Comment: @PedrodeSá just forget add that part, you can chain at the 2nd line s.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>=5]

Comment: I'm getting a "Memory Error" but it's not displaying any final messages like I'm used to see

Comment: @PedrodeSá how about do it columns by column with for loop ?

Comment: The thing is just changing the threshold from 5 to 72, for example, in your code and Quang Huang's code here below I get different answers and I don't know why thats happening

Comment: I think doing for loops will take a really long time because the dataframe is really big

Comment: @PedrodeSá `limit=5;
l=[df[x].groupby([df[x],df[x].diff().ne(0).cumsum()]).size().loc[lambda x : x>=limit] for x in list(df)]` , try this should be fast, for loop no always bad .

Comment: This seems to give the same output as Quang Hoang's answer. Do you know if it's possible to add in this one-liner a way to not count null values? I'd like to share a print with you from the output so you could see but if I understood correctly the code is counting also null values

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to find the consecutive blocks *within* each column and add their sizes up:

```
# compare cells with previous 
# and stack into a series
s = df.eq(df.shift()).melt()

# groups of consecutive equal values
groups = (~s['value']).groupby(s['variable']).cumsum()

(s.groupby(['variable', groups])
  .size()
  .loc[lambda x: x>=5]          # stole from BEN's answer
  .groupby(level=0).sum()       # replace this line with sum(level=0) would also work
)
```

Output:

```
variable
A    8
B    5
C    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Quang Hoang! This is precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: Hey @Quang Hoang, is there any way to show the amount of each value it's repeating it self per variable (A, B, C, ...) like the updated version of YOBEN_S' answer? In my example above for equipment A we only have the value 47 repeating, but if we have, let's say, 47 and 55, its possible to display the amount of repeated values for each of this two values?